# xcb correct window size

Tags: c++, xcb

I have a question regarding xcb Window size
I create a window using `xcb_create_window` function

```
    xcb_create_window(mScreen->connection(),
                  XCB_COPY_FROM_PARENT,
                  mWindow,
                  mScreen->screen()->root,
                  x, // left corner of the window client area
                  y, // upper corner of the window client area
                  width, // width of the client area
                  height, // height of the client area
                  0,
                  XCB_WINDOW_CLASS_INPUT_OUTPUT,
                  mScreen->screen()->root_visual,
                  value_mask,
                  value_list);
    auto reply = XCB_REPLY(xcb_intern_atom, mScreen->connection(), true, strlen("WM_PROTOCOLS"), "WM_PROTOCOLS");
    auto atomDelete = XCB_REPLY(xcb_intern_atom, mScreen->connection(), false, strlen("WM_DELETE_WINDOW"), "WM_DELETE_WINDOW");

    xcb_change_property(mScreen->connection(), XCB_PROP_MODE_REPLACE, mWindow, reply->atom, 4, 32, 1, &atomDelete->atom);
    xcb_change_property(mScreen->connection(), XCB_PROP_MODE_REPLACE, mWindow, XCB_ATOM_WM_NAME, XCB_ATOM_STRING, 8, strlen(windowName), windowName);
    xcb_flush(mScreen->connection());
```

On Win32 API I have the possibilty to adjust a window rect by using `AdjustWindowRect` function which basically adds border and caption size to ensure client window does have the expected size.

My question how do I achieve this with xcb? Is there any way to compute the additonal size that is needed to ensure client window das have the expected size?

Comment: Two things: I read your question as "I know what how the Win32 API works and now I want to do the same thing on X11". Well, I do *not* know Win32, so please clarify your question. What is the behaviour you are seeing and what is the desired behaviour?

Comment: Second thing: I asked Google for `AdjustWindowRect` and apparently in Win32 you need to add space for the titlebar. In X11, there is no such thing. If you ask for a 10x15 window, you get a window of exactly that size. Put differently: What is the actual problem that you are seeing?

Comment: Put differently: In X11, you request your desired window size. Titlebars and decorations are added outside of that. Apparently, in Windows these decorations are "subtracted" from your space. Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: Ok win32 is a bit misleading and I thought this is well known c api so most developers know it... The window size seems to include decorations so I want have the exact size to ensure client rect to be the given size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code gets margins of a window
followed suggestion from Erdal Küçük:

- create window
- configure stuff (like title or close button)
- wait for property message
- in case _NET_FRAME_EXTENTS read data

  ```
    uint32_t value_mask, value_list[32]{};
    auto windowHandle = xcb_generate_id(xcb_connection());
    value_mask = XCB_CW_EVENT_MASK;
    value_list[0] = XCB_EVENT_MASK_PROPERTY_CHANGE;

    xcb_create_window(screen->connection(),
                      XCB_COPY_FROM_PARENT,
                      windowHandle,
                      screen->root,
                      100,
                      100,
                      100,
                      100,
                      0,
                      XCB_WINDOW_CLASS_INPUT_OUTPUT,
                      screen->root_visual,
                      value_mask,
                      value_list);

    auto protocols = XCB_REPLY(xcb_intern_atom, screen->connection(), true, strlen("WM_PROTOCOLS"), "WM_PROTOCOLS");
    auto atomDelete = XCB_REPLY(xcb_intern_atom, screen->connection(), false, strlen("WM_DELETE_WINDOW"), "WM_DELETE_WINDOW");
    auto atomExtents = XCB_REPLY(xcb_intern_atom, screen->connection(), false, strlen("_NET_FRAME_EXTENTS"), "_NET_FRAME_EXTENTS");

    xcb_change_property(xcb_connection(), XCB_PROP_MODE_REPLACE, windowHandle, protocols->atom, XCB_ATOM_ATOM, 32, 1, &atomDelete->atom);
    xcb_change_property(xcb_connection(), XCB_PROP_MODE_REPLACE, windowHandle, XCB_ATOM_WM_NAME, XCB_ATOM_STRING, 8, strlen(""), "");
    xcb_map_window(xcb_connection(), windowHandle);
    xcb_flush(xcb_connection());
    xcb_generic_event_t* event;

    for (;;) {
        while ((event = xcb_poll_for_event(screen->connection()))) {
            switch (event->response_type & 0x7f) {
                case XCB_PROPERTY_NOTIFY: {
                    auto propertyNotify = (const xcb_property_notify_event_t*)event;

                    if (propertyNotify->atom == atomExtents->atom) {
                        free(event);
                        goto end;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    break;
            }
            free(event);
        }
    }
    end:
    auto extends = XCB_REPLY(xcb_get_property, xcb_connection(), false, windowHandle, atomExtents->atom, XCB_ATOM_CARDINAL, 0, 4);
    if (extends && extends->type == XCB_ATOM_CARDINAL && extends->format == 32 && extends->value_len == 4) {
        uint32_t* data = std::pointer_cast<uint32_t*>(xcb_get_property_value(extends.get()));
        windowMargins.l = -data[0];
        windowMargins.r = data[1];
        windowMargins.t = -data[2];
        windowMargins.b = data[3];
    }

    xcb_destroy_window(xcb_connection(), windowHandle);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

[Extended Window Manager Hints](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/latest/)

[_NET_REQUEST_FRAME_EXTENTS](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/latest/ar01s04.html#idm46476783527760) (Other Root Window Messages)

> Rationale: A client cannot calculate the dimensions of its window's frame before the window is mapped, but some toolkits need this information. Asking the window manager for an estimate of the extents is a workable solution. The estimate may depend on the current theme, font sizes or other window properties. The client can track changes to the frame's dimensions by listening for _NET_FRAME_EXTENTS PropertyNotify events.

[_NET_FRAME_EXTENTS](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/latest/ar01s05.html#idm46476783436400) (Application Window Properties)

> The Window Manager MUST set _NET_FRAME_EXTENTS to the extents of the window's frame. left, right, top and bottom are widths of the respective borders added by the Window Manager.

Examples can be found here:

- [xcb_intern_atom](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/3-xcb_intern_atom#lbAL) ([api](https://xcb.freedesktop.org/manual/group__XCB____API.html#ga5c9806a2cfa188c38ed35bff51c60410))
- [xcb_get_property](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/3-xcb_get_property#lbAM) ([api](https://xcb.freedesktop.org/manual/group__XCB____API.html#ga86312758f2d011c375ae23ac2c063b7d))

Comment: can you give a code example how use it please?

Comment: These are atoms, you retrieve them via `xcb_intern_atom` and `xcb_get_property`. Read the provided links about the required data types (`CARDINAL[4]/32`).

Comment: I would like to give you an example but i've never used xcb before, only xlib, sorry.

Comment: I saw the documentation you state before but for me it is pretty much unclear how to use it. some say use xcb_property some say its an notify event

Comment: Well it's both. If you configure the client to receive PropertyNotify events, then you will receive such events if that specific property (atom) has changed. But you can also directly request the value of that property. I've found some examples (links added to my answer), have a look at those.